# custom add icon in gravity forms wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a list field that can add multiple rows, as default it has an image with a plus sign. I want to change it using the following code but nothing's happened:

```
    .gfield_list_icons{     
       position: relative; 
    }

    .gfield_list_icons img:after {   
      font-family:'Arial';
      content: 'Add more';      
      padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;     
      color: #FFF;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #9D9D9D; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add !important >> content: 'Add more' !important; or hide the img "plus sign" and used

```
.gfield_list_icons:after {   
  font-family:'Arial';
  content: 'Add more';      
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;     
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #9D9D9D;
```

}